# Is there a way to build my own "Portable" Windows AMP (Apache, MySQL, PHP) Stack?

Tags: windows, php, apache-http-server, mysql, portable

I know there are things like XAMPP thats portable, but it does not use latest version of the software, can I build my own?

I prefer portable stuff as they don't require installs, won't be affected if I format my Windows

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP already [is portable](http://pages.citebite.com/q3p5r1o9osor) if you run it from the root of a drive (that is, `X:\` and not `X:\Path\`) and you don't run the setup script.

There are [alternatives](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?sc=125) but none of them can hold a candle to XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few guides that you can find on Google that show how to update the versions of software that they have

Eg: http://thephpcode.blogspot.com/2008/06/upgrading-mysql-with-xampp-installed.html

Answer (score 0):

You can install Apache, PHP, and MySQL manually. Here is a detailed instruction on [another superuser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/748117/how-to-manually-install-apache-php-and-mysql-on-windows).

Place your files in drive D instead of placing it in drive C. Should you reformat your drive C, you only need to reinstall the Visual C++ runtimes (needed by PHP and Apache binaries) and the Apache and MySQL windows services. Your files and configuration (httpd.conf, php.ini) are unaffected.